# What is the difference between android:tint and android:fillColor in VectorDrawables?

Tags: android, xml, colors

Usually when we create a new Vector Asset Clip Art inside android studio the ide create an xml code like this

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="24dp" 
    >
    <path 
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M21,6h-2v9L6,15v2c0,0.55 0.45,1 1,1h11l4,4L22,7c0,-0.55 -0.45,-1 -1,-1zM17,12L17,3c0,-0.55 -0.45,-1 -1,-1L3,2c-0.55,0 -1,0.45 -1,1v14l4,-4h10c0.55,0 1,-0.45 1,-1z"/>
</vector>
```

we notice that there is two different attributes has a color value 
`tint` and `fillColor` what is the diffrences between those attributes and how they effect on the icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fill color is the color the path is filled with. A tint just filters the colors with that shade. It's like a semi-transparent overlay to nudge the pixels towards that color. You can easily change the tint in the various display properties you can't necessarily recolor paths. It will also let you reuse the icon with different color schemes more effectively.

Comment: so I can delete fill color attribute and only use tint?

Comment: If you did that it would fill the color with the default. I think black. Then tint wouldn't do nearly as much. Usually they do different stuff. You want to fill it with whatever color is correct. Then if you have some kind of theme'd thing you'd then apply some tints. It depends entirely on what you want to do.